# MySQL Products to ClientsPriceList Database Design Issue

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, foreign-keys

[image]

Product table.

[image]

Pricelist table.

I have a product table and a pricelist table which get linking together for the purpose of getting the price of each product based on client(column name). I'm wondering if my design is alright? What is more efficient? a column for each client's pricelist or a table for each client's pricelist?

Comment: Yes, there's a better way. See normalisation.

Comment: @Strawberry Please provide some info for guidance.

Comment: A normalised  table might look like this: `product_id,client_id,price`, where product_id and client_id are components of a compound PRIMARY KEY

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks. You enlightened me :)

Comment: @Strawberry Do i really need to index product_id and client_id to be able to set foreign key constraints? Even though I won't be needing any primary key in this table.

Comment: You should always have a PRIMARY KEY. In an RDBMS, a table isn't really a table without one.

Comment: @Strawberry I set product_id together with client_id as composite primary key. Am I doing it right?

Comment: Yes. That's called a NATURAL KEY, as opposed to a SURROGATE KEY

Comment: `Product` look like it has an array of "clients".  That is _not_ a good way to do a many-to-many mapping.